# Bootstrap Divs or Container covered background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I have this problem whereby my page style with bootstrap div container for the sign in forms and top portion logo, this part however covered or blank out my intended background image styled using CSS

```
html{
  background: url("Bg1.jpg")no-repeat center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  -moz-background-size:cover;
  -o-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
  margin:0;
}
```

and my the 2 containers where I place a logo on top and the sign in form in the middle

```
<div class="container"><!--top portion-->
  <div class="row"> <!--logo portion-->
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
  <a href="#"><img class="image-responsive img-rounded" alt="B-Flight" src="Logo1.png" id="banner" /></a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-0"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-0"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-0"></div>
</div><!--row-->

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"></div><!--left column of whole page-->
<div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
<title>Login</title>
  <form class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading align-center">Sign In</h2>
    <label for="usrName" class="Titlefont">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="usrName" class="form-control" placeholder="user name" required autofocus><br>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <br>
    <a href="signup.html"><button class="btn btn-link btn-block" type="button">Not registered? Sign up now</button></a>
  </form>
</div><!--set alignment-->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"></div><!--right column of the page-->
</div><!--row-->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

And there photo of it [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcTaB.jpg)

Appreciate if anyone be able to help out

Thanks

Comment: You likely need to add a property of `background:none;` to the elements that cover your intended background. Firebug (firefox) is a good help in finding the element. From what you show it is hard to say, because the CSS is missing of the elements that causes this.

Comment: I just tried adding the `background:none;`to the `.container{...}` class in CSS. However it still doesnt appear to solve the issue. But I do appreciate your time answering and providing an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the background-color of `body` is set to white.
So when you style your `html` the `body` is not targeted and still white.
You might instead want to try using

```
html, body {
    /* Your CSS goes here */
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This appears to be a bootstrap default to have the body background white. Just to add a little note to it.